# Getting names and number of selected features before giving to a classifier in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using `sel = SelectFromModel(ExtraTreesClassifier(10), threshold='mean')` to select the most important features in my data set.

Then I want to feed these selected features to my keras classifier. But my keras based Neural Network classifier needs the number of imprtant features selected in the first step. Below is the code for my keras classifier and the variable `X_new` is the numpy array of new features selected.

The code for keras classifier is as under.

```
def create_model( 
             dropout=0.2):

n_x_new=X_new.shape[1]
np.random.seed(6000)
model_new = Sequential()
model_new.add(Dense(n_x_new, input_dim=n_x_new, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model_new.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model_new.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_new.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model_new.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['binary_crossentropy'])

return model_new

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed) 

clf=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=1000, verbose=0)


param_grid = {'clf__dropout':[0.1,0.2]}
model = Pipeline([('sel', sel),('clf', clf),])


grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(np.concatenate((train_x_upsampled, cross_val_x_upsampled), axis=0), np.concatenate((train_y_upsampled, cross_val_y_upsampled), axis=0))
```

As I am using Pipline with grid search, I don't understand how my neural network will get the important features selected in the first step. I want to get those important features selected into an array of `X_new`.

Do I need to implement a custom estimator in between `sel` and `keras model`?

If yes, How would I implement one? I know the generic code for custom estimator but I am unable to mold it according to my requirement. The generic code is as under.

```
class new_features(TransformerMixin):
def transform(self, X):
    X_new = sel.transform(X)
    return X_new
```

But this is not working. Is there any way I can solve this problem without using custom estimator in between?

Comment: This will be automatically done by the pipeline. Your neural network will get the `X_new` (after `sel.transform()`). Do you want to use that `X_new` to do something else?

Comment: @VivekKumar... Do I need to define `sel.transform()` somewhere in my code ? How will neural network know about the important features that it would need for training. I just want that my neural network should be trained only on new important features selected. and then I will want to know later on the names of the features selected after the training and testing is done.

Comment: Or do you want the names of features selected by the `sel`? If yes, then `model.named_steps['sel'].get_support()` to get the indices of selected features.

Comment: No, you do not need to define `sel.transform()`. This will be done by the pipeline. For all the intermediate steps, the pipeline will automatically call `fit()` and then `transform()`. This transformed data will be passed on to next estimator in pipeline.

Comment: @VivekKumar   then what should be the value of my `X_new` variable in the my keras model in the second line. Do I still need to define it? If not, what should I write in `input_dim=n_x_new`

Comment: I only want that my neural network should be trained on selected feature by `sel`.

Comment: No, unfortunately I could not find anything which does this in a simple way. The recommended way is to make a custom wrapper over the Keras model which in `fit()` method will count the shape of data and compile the model accordingly.

Comment: @VivekKumar..But I have already defined a custom wrapper around keras model with a name  `KerasClassifier`.

Comment: Yes I agree. But thats to make the keras model compatible with scikit. The wrapper I am talking about is to compile the model with new number of features.